# Summary by state/county total line or running line

Tags: sql

In this Query, I would like to show the total of clients by state/county. Is this possible?
I guess a running total is ok in new column or if possible a break when the state/county changes to show the total of the previous count?
So output like this>

```
|first_name|last_name|description|description|
VIN ULTI New York Bronx 1
MEL MORRIS New York Bronx 2
BYRAM BROWN New York Bronx 3 or preferred a line total:
*** Total Clients Bronx New York = 3
SELMA MADDISON New York Queens 1
*** Total Clients New York Queens = 1

select ac.first_name, ac.last_name, st.description, co.description
from address ad
inner join all_clients_view ac
  on ad.people_id = ac.people_id
inner join county co
  on ad.county = co.county_id
inner join state st
  on co.state_id = st.state_id
where ad.is_active = 1
order by st.description, co.description
```

Comment: a [mre] contains tables and data, so please produce it, your data makes not much send

Answer (score 0):

You can try with these scripts:

```
1) Total of the previuos count:

    select ac.first_name, ac.last_name, st.description, co.description,
           (select count(*)
              from address ad2
                   inner join all_clients_view ac2
                           on ad2.people_id = ac2.people_id
                   inner join county co2
                           on ad2.county    = co2.county_id
                   inner join state st2
                           on co2.state_id = st2.state_id
            where ad2.is_active  = 1
              and ad2.county     = ad.county 
              and ad2.people_id <= ad.people_id)
           as count_progress
      from address ad
           inner join all_clients_view ac
                   on ad.people_id = ac.people_id
           inner join county co
                   on ad.county    = co.county_id
           inner join state st     
                   on co.state_id  = st.state_id
    where ad.is_active = 1
    order by st.description, co.description, ad.people_id;
    
    FIRST LAST_NAM DESCRIPT DESCRI COUNT_PROGRESS
    ----- -------- -------- ------ --------------
    VIN   ULTI     New York Bronx               1
    MEL   MORRIS   New York Bronx               2
    BYRAM BROWN    New York Bronx               3
    SELMA MADDISON New York Queens              1

2) Line Total:

    select st.description as state, co.description as county, count(*)
      from address ad
           inner join all_clients_view ac
                   on ad.people_id = ac.people_id
           inner join county co
                   on ad.county    = co.county_id
           inner join state st
                   on co.state_id  = st.state_id
    where ad.is_active = 1
    group by st.description, co.description
    order by st.description, co.description;
    
    STATE    COUNTY   COUNT(*)
    -------- ------ ----------
    New York Bronx           3
    New York Queens          1
```

Thank you.